# Missing some polygons while clipping

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

I keep on missing some polygons while clipping a gdb file with a circle (shape file).
I guess it comes from the "invalid geometry" error I get but do not know how to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/29/fixing-invalid-polygon-geometries/

Comment: Using the Fix Geometries processing algorithm is usually a great hands-off first pass that fixes issues with GDB-sourced vector data for me 99/100 times.